# Can I have multiple OP_RETURN outputs in one transaction?

Tags: transactions, op-return

I am wondering if I can inject multiple OP_RETURN outputs in one transaction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can inject multiple OP_RETURN outputs in one transaction?

At the protocol level, absolutely nothing prevents you from doing this. However, such a transaction would not be considered a 'standard' transaction and would not be relayed (propagated) through the network.

Let's say, though, you were a miner yourself. Then you could mine a transaction with 100 OP_RETURN outputs in it, and no one would reject your block because of it.

Comment: I'm confused, because I found a transaction with three `OP_RETURN` outputs in it: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d8ca2c1cc697c4125d2bd5bcbaa5c3a6a54e32752d29ccb0244ed7ce24bdcbaf So it is possible now ?

Comment: @csstudent1418 I misread the answer too. So multiple OP_RETURNs are only denied in propagating txs, not blocks. So, only a miner can do multiple OP_RETURNs as their transaction doesn't need to be propagated. The tx you point out is a coinbase tx, and thus comes from the miner.